# How to generate documentation for Clojure code on Windows?

Tags: windows, clojure, documentation

I can't seem to find a way to generate documentation for Clojure code on Windows.

- Marginalia seems to be broken on all platforms since 1.7 (see here:
  https://github.com/gdeer81/marginalia/issues/158).
- Codox has an issue
  open on this topic (https://github.com/weavejester/codox/issues/110).
- The Autodoc plugin for Lein 2 seems to be broken as well    (not
  enough reputation to post more than two links, but there's an issue
  open on this over at GitHub).

Has anyone succeeded in running any of these three on Windows? Should I try something else?

Note:

1. I do not have a choice here, it must run on Windows.
2. As I'm building a case for clojure in the company, it must play well with leiningen, which is used to build and test our code.

Comment: did you try the [patched marginalia](https://clojars.org/michaelblume/marginalia) jar from the linked github issue?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. Relying on this would either break the build chain (where the doc tool would be pulled from Clojars/Maven repos via Leiningen) or require us to set up a dedicated, possibly temporary repo. Before we do that, I would like to make sure there's nothing else to be done. Also, as I trying to sell Clojure internally, having to rely on a non-standard version of a tool would not look too good.

Comment: The Marginalia issue linked to (#158) was fixed a couple of years ago, and Marginalia was recently updated to work on Clojure 1.9 as well. Perhaps you could try the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [autodoc](https://github.com/tomfaulhaber/autodoc) - seems to still be active, but from the README it seems there are no promises it works on windows - still you could give it a try.

I think codox might still be your best bet. It's pretty popular and well maintained (there's only 4 open bugs right now and they're pretty newish - one of which is the one you referenced in your question). So maybe give it some time.

Finally, I know this is probably obvious and not ideal, but you could at least do one-off generations of documentation on a *nix system for the time being.

Comment: Regarding autodoc, do you suggest I bypass lein (and its plugin) and use the tool directly? Your other suggestion, however sensible, wouldn't work for my case, as the problem is part technical, part political. We really should be able to use a documentation generation tool on any one of our development platform, and this includes Windows. I'll keep an eye on Codox, since even though I find the doc produced by Marginalia beautiful, Codox might be easier to sell.